# CEDET: storing tags manually

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb

I'm using ECB with Cedet - and semantic search engine stores tags about the files I visit in its cache files.

I'm also using ECB's `left-symboldef` layout - which shows definition of the tag the cursor is on. In order to do that semantic opens the file where the tag was defined.

The problem is - semantic opens almost all of my python scripts all the time - since I have `parser` defined in all of them - when I parse command line arguments with `argparse`... So I'd rather stop semantic caching my files automatically, and do it manually with `C-c , ,` on my libs only.

So my question is - how do I prevent semantic from storing cache? I should still be able to use the existing database (which I'll collect manually).

Comment: Or maybe I got it all in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the automatic parsing of other files in idle time, you can set:

```
(setq semantic-idle-work-parse-neighboring-files-flag nil)
```

and if it is pulling them in via includes, you can do this:

```
(setq semantic-idle-work-update-headers-flag nil)
```

This is actually the default, and it gets set to true if you use one of the canned configuration options for regular or gaudy code helpers.

In order to not parse all the files, but still let ECB find tag definitions, you will probably need to use a GNU Global database.  See `semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases` for more.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. A note though - I want semantic to parse files - but I don't want it to store chache files. I want to store chache files manually - on invoking `C-c , ,`.

Comment: You can manually save with semanticdb-save-all-db.  There is no option for disabling save during idle time.  If you disable the parsing of neighboring files, however, it won't need to save anything, and thus won't get in your way.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But what about files I open myself? Will it store the cache for that files? I want semantic to parse them - but no storing. I'd like to store cache manaully - on invoking `C-c , ,`.

Comment: You can disable saving by disabling global-semanticdb-minor-mode, but when it is active, everything that you open will be saved.  If you re-enable after it has been disabled, it will only save open buffers, or buffers that were previously saved in the current directory.  This case is untested though, so YMMV.